# How to use hamcrest contains to compare 2 lists?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Why does this test fail? I know contains works when you pass in individual strings separated by commas but I wanted to see if it's possible to just pass in an entire list of strings instead. I just want to make sure that list 1 contains all of the contents of list 2.

```
@Test
public void testContains() {
    String expected1 = "hello";
    String expected2 = "goodbye";
    List<String> expectedStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    expectedStrings.add(expected1);
    expectedStrings.add(expected2);
    List<String> actualStrings = new ArrayList<>();
    actualStrings.add(expected1);
    actualStrings.add(expected2);
    assertThat(actualStrings, contains(expectedStrings));
}
```

Is it considered acceptable to use this assertion instead?

```
assertThat(actualStrings, is(expectedStrings));
```

Comment: containsAll instead of contains. check [API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#containsAll-java.util.Collection-)

Comment: @RahulSharma so you would use it like `assertThat(actualStrings.containsAll(expectedStrings), is(true))`?

Comment: @RahulSharma I was looking more for if there is a hamcrest matcher similar to the List method `containsAll` so I can do this instead: `assertThat(actualStrings, containsAll(expectedStrings))`. I think it reads better than the `is(true)` matcher.

Comment: I don't really know how to do that with hamcrest. I use JUnit asserts in my tests. JUnit has most of the hamcrest functionality pulled in, if using hamcrest is not mandatory in your case I would suggest using JUnit.

Comment: @RahulSharma Ok so what would your JUnit assert look like in this case?

Comment: assertTrue(actualStrings.containsAll(expectedStrings))

Comment: @RahulSharma Ah ok. I've just been trying to get in the habit of using assertThat instead of assertTrue b/c of the better failure messages. But yes this will work. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry just curious what do you mean 'Better failure messages'?

Comment: @RahulSharma Check out this article -> https://objectpartners.com/2013/09/18/the-benefits-of-using-assertthat-over-other-assert-methods-in-unit-tests/

Comment: @RahulSharma Also here -> http://stackoverflow.com/a/1701143/4702682

Comment: The article and the answer are quite old, 2013 and 2012. Things have changed over the years. Every single drawback of assertTrue(or other methods) which is mentioned in the article has been improved and incorporated. AssertTrue now gives the complete failure message with the values of actual and expected. Also the assert methods allow you to add custom message which sometimes are quite helpful

Comment: @RahulSharma That's interesting, I'll have to look into that. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no overloaded `contains` method which takes a list of expected values.

In the statement `assertThat(actualStrings, contains(expectedStrings))`
the following method (in the `Matchers` class) is called:

```
<E> org.hamcrest.Matcher<java.lang.Iterable<? extends E>> contains(E... items)
```

Basically you are saying that you expect a list with one element and this element is `expectedStrings` but in fact it is `expected1` (`E` is of type `List<String>` and not `String`). To verify add the following to the test which should then pass:

```
List<List<String>> listOfactualStrings = new ArrayList<>();
listOfactualStrings.add(actualStrings);
assertThat(listOfactualStrings, contains(expectedStrings));
```

---

To make the assertion work you have to convert the list to an array:

```
assertThat(actualStrings, contains(expectedStrings.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply a matcher for each item in a list you can use the `everyItem` matcher, like so:

```
everyItem(not(isEmptyOrNullString()))
```